# How to set variables for all subsequent hosts in one place without redundant code?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

TL/DR: I have "src_host" and "dest_host" variables that I want to use to set the "- hosts:" object in a play. However, I have to set them again for each play under "vars:" of each "- hosts:" section e.g. src_host="{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}" how do I set these two variables at the beginning and not have to reset them?

My hosts file looks like this

```
[wordpress]
localhost ansible_user=user ansible_port=22 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
root_localhost ansible_user=root ansible_port=22 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

---snip---

server2.net ansible_host="server2.net" ansible_user=user ansible_port=22 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
root_server2.net ansible_host="server2.net" ansible_user=root ansible_port=22  ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The beginning of my playbook looks like this:

```
- hosts: localhost, server2.net, root_server2.net #always include "localhost" in this list because it is needed to store the variables for the src_host and dest_host
  vars:
    src_host: localhost #modify these and the host will be changed for all subsequent plays/tasks
    dest_host: server2.net #modify these and the host will be changed for all subsequent plays/tasks
    src_dump_path: /home/user/cvrt9_dump.sql #set vars for copying file
  roles:  
    - set_facts_for_db_copy

- hosts: "{{ src_host }}" 
  vars: 
    src_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"
    dest_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['dest_host'] }}"
    ---snip---
  roles:
    - dump_db
    - copy_file
```

etc . . .

for "- set_facts_for_db_copy" I have "main.yml" as this where I set the "src_host" and "dest_host" variables:

```
---
# tasks file for set_facts_for_db_copy
- name: create variables that equal src_dump_path and set src_host/dest_host
  set_fact:
    ---snip---
    src_host: "{{ src_host }}"
    dest_host: "{{ dest_host }}"
```

So I need to set the "src_host" and "dest_host" for all subsequent "- hosts:" that use them by getting the values from one of the host variables that "set_fact_for_db_copy" set. I randomly picked "localhost" as you may have noticed:

```
src_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"
dest_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['dest_host'] }}"
```

If I don't have that line there I get:

```
user@localhost:/home/maintainer/ansible-play$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_tat-kay playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost, server2.net, root_server2.net] **************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [server2.net]
ok: [root_server2.net]
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_facts_for_db_copy : create variables that equal src_dump_path] *******
ok: [localhost]
ok: [server2.net]
ok: [root_server2.net]
ERROR! the field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'src_host' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/home/maintainer/ansible-play/playbook.yml': line 14, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: "{{ src_host }}" 
  ^ here
```

. . .

Now I can set the these variables in my host file:

```
[wordpress:vars]
src_host=localhost
dest_host=server2.net
```

But then I still have to reference them from the subsquent "-hosts:" objects in my playbook with "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}" etc . . . So my question is how do I get rid of this redundant code in all my subsequent "-hosts:" objects (shown below) while still letting me change the "src_host" and "dest_host" variables once at the beginning and have those changes affect the rest of the plays? Thanks.

```
    src_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"
    dest_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['dest_host'] }}"
```

Comment: In the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the Help Center, there is an advice: "***Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence*". Take it.

Comment: @techraf Thanks for the constructive criticism. I snipped some things out and added a TL/DR summary at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/users/4716639/bryan-calvo-benoit is to put this in my hosts file (inventory file)

```
[wordpress] 
localhost 
server2.net 

[testenv:children] 
wordpress 

[testenv:vars] 
src_host=localhost 
dest_host=server2.net
```

And then in the ansible playbook and the roles that it calls I had to replace

```
"{{ src_host }}"
```

with

```
"{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"
```

and likewise for "{{ dest_host }}"

However, I could delete this redundant code in my ansible playbook:

```
src_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"
dest_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['dest_host'] }}"
```

It would be nice if I didn't have to change the src_host and dest_host to hostvars['localhost']... because it seems arbitrary to use localhost and also what if I want to run several ansible scripts one right after the other with different src_host and dest_host? Using the inventory file locks it down so this is not ideal. If no one else answers I'll accept this answer because it is the only one that works and it technically does what my question asked.

Answer (score 1):

For this use your inventory file, make a parent group of the host you need the variable as follow.

```
[desireenv:children]
wordpress
otherhost
etc
```

and then assigne th vars value to the new parent group created

```
[desireenv:vars]
src_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"
dest_host: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['dest_host'] }}"
```

Comment: Just got a chance to look back at this. Your answer doesn't appear to work.

"ERROR! the field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'src_host' is undefined"

Do both the [desireenv:children] section and [desireenv:vars] section go in the hosts file?

I am running it like so:
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

Comment: ok I got it to work but instead I had to have this in my hosts file:
[wordpress]
localhost
server2.net


[testenv:children]
wordpress

[testenv:vars]
src_host=localhost
dest_host=server2.net

and then in the ansible script and the roles that it called I had to replace "{{ src_host }}" with "{{ hostvars['localhost']['src_host'] }}"  and likewise for "{{ dest_host }}"